# Textbox won't update total

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display a total in a text box however the variable the text box outputs will only update if the value assigned to it is greater than the last value instead of adding to the last value.

```
private void PictureBoxWindFarmMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  decimal captot = 0;
  // Read mouse-click position
  int x = e.X;
  int y = e.Y;
  //collects varibles from the form 
  int hei = _heightTrackBar.Value;
  float rad = (_radiusTrackBar.Value)*0.01f ;
  int bla = Convert.ToInt32(_numberOfBladesUpDown.Value);
  Color pol = colorDialog1.Color;
  Color rot = colorDialog2.Color;
  bool clo = _clockwiseCheckBox.Checked;
  decimal cap = _capacityUpDown.Value;
  captot +=  cap;
  // Create wind turbine at this position, uses collected varibles
  WindTurbine turbine = new WindTurbine( hei, rad, bla, clo, pol, rot, cap, x, y);
  // Add wind turbine to farm list
  _turbines.Add(turbine);
  // Force redraw of the picture box to show changes
  _pictureBoxWindFarm.Refresh();
  _statusLabel.ResetText();
  _statusLabel.Text = ("these"+ _turbines.Count + "wind turbines can generate a total of" + captot + "MW of power.");
}
```

[textbox at lower left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5m78.png)

[textbox not adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80XdJ.png)

[updates if value is greater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ4ry.png)

Comment: Are you supposed to reset a captot variable each time you click the picturebox...shouldn't it be a variable set outside of the eventhandler?

Comment: What TextBox ? Also have you debugged this. Do you know how to use the step debugger ?

Comment: You are initializing `catpot` to 0 and adding only the capacity of the newly created turbine. So how would the screen display the total capacity?

Comment: the captot variable is meant to start at 0 and add cap to itself then display itself in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

GI1 was right the variable just needed to be declared outside the event